# Token Validation - Angular

Tags: angular, jwt, token

Is it possible to verify the token on FrontEnd (TypeScript). So I do not want to know if the token has expired (Because someone can change the contents of the token, but the token can still be vague). I want to make sure that the token is valid. Is it possible to that on FrontEnd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Check expiration

If you want to check the expiration of a token, then you need to decode its "exp" claim. You can decode a JWT at front end without security issues. 
Retrieve the "Expires at" claim and do your calculations.

### Verify

This is a little bit more problematic, since in order to verify a JWT you need to verify the signature using your *secret*, if you want to verify at front-end then your secret needs to be available at the front-end, which is a major security issue, since it will probably be exposed to your users.

I personally am not aware of a way to store a secret at front-end without exposing it to your user.